# Retrieving Country (ISO 3166-1) and Region (ISO 3166-2) codes from address (using existing web services)

Tags: php, web-services, geocoding, iso, iso-3166

Are there any web services or DBs available that will be able to return the ISO 3166-1 and ISO 3166-2 (Country & region) codes given a particular address or latitude/longitude coordinates?

I'm currently using the Google Geocode API in a PHP app, and would like to augment that info with the above mentioned ISO codes.

Thanks very much.

Prembo.

Comment: Thank you Peter - that did answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[How to reverse geocode without Google?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513134/how-to-reverse-geocode-without-google) contains an answer that would do the job.  (Thanks @peter-szymkowski)

The Web Service that can be used is provided by: www.geonames.org

- Country Code: http://api.geonames.org/countryCode
- ISO 3166-2 Region Code: http://api.geonames.org/countrySubdivision

Comment: Does this still work?