# html5 geolocation for user location in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, geolocation

i want to get the user location information like city, area etc using html5 geolocation,i tried the below article but with that im getting latitude and longitude, i want to get the city and area information, 
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=782

Answer (score 0):

When you have the location of the user, you'll need to do a reverse geocoding to get information about the location such as city, etc.

Have a look at the [reverse geocoding API for Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding).

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        console.log(results);
        // Analyze results and find the info you need.
    });
});
```

Check out [How to reverse geocode without Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513134/how-to-reverse-geocode-without-google) for information about geocoding without using Google Maps.

Comment: can we add maps below and point out the address based on the latitute and longitude

Comment: Do you want to display the map with the user's location? http://gazpo.com/2011/11/geolocation/

Comment: yes, with user location on it as in the above url with google maps