# Sort a list by distance using reversed Geolocation

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, cllocation, reversegeocodelocation

I'm using Xcode 7 with iOS9.  I want to sort a list ascending, based on distance from users current location to all other locations in the list.

I don't want to calculate the distance to a location by coordinates, but by address because the distance depends on the choosen method (drive / walk). All I want to do is save the address in each location object to calculate the distance to that object later on.

When initializing the list with objects I'm doing this request in each object's initializer:

```
let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude) //changed!!!

CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in 
    //the code to obtain an address and save it in a location object is here and works
}
```

The problem I have now is that I have to send 172 such reverseGeocodeLocation requests as my list contains 172 objects and I need to calculate the distance from my users location to each object's location.

Sending so many requests so fast results in this error:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 2.)

Is there a way to solve this?
If things aren't clear tell me please so I can clarify

Comment: I don't think this is really the intended use of the reverseGeocodeLocation, so without spacing out your requests to meet the API limit, I doubt there will be a good solution. Have you looked into using a different Geolocation service with a different API limit or that allows you to send more than one location at a time

Comment: sort a list ascending means you are going to list those nearby places??

Comment: @anishparajuli yes exactly

Comment: use google places API or foursquare API then... ??

Comment: @anishparajuli Yes google api works fine, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself with help of some comments here.

At the moment, the only distance that can be retrieved using Apple Maps API is the straight line distance between coordinates. However if you want to **calculate real distances** between two addresses or coordinates you can do it **[with the Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro)** by sending a simple request.

## Example:

Calculate the distance from: 51.226531,4.190688

to 51.114476,4.139618 and 51.148123,4.182590.

You can simply do this with this API call:
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=51.226531,4.190688&destinations=51.114476,4.139618|51.148123,4.182590](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=51.226531,4.190688&destinations=51.114476,4.139618%7C51.148123,4.182590)

Notice i'm using 3  parameters: 
*json*: the format in which I want the result to be returned
*origins*: the coordinates/address where you start
*destinations*: multiple coordinates/addresses seperated by " | "

This is the result from the call:

```
{
  "destination_addresses" : [
  "Dorpstraat 70, 9140 Temse, België",
  "Eigenlostraat 38, 9100 Sint-Niklaas, België"
],
"origin_addresses" : [ "Provinciale Baan 37, 9120 Beveren, België" ],
"rows" : [
  {
     "elements" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "16,3 km",
              "value" : 16346
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "22 min.",
              "value" : 1321
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        },
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "10,5 km",
              "value" : 10521
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "17 min.",
              "value" : 1003
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        }
     ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK" 
}
```

If things aren't clear, ask me!

Comment: anyway there is not different than this "172 such reverseGeocodeLocation requests as my list contains 172 objects"..just you wont get the error but for client side you will be calling a lot  API?

Comment: that's what I thought at first as well but if you read the API well, you can retrieve multiple distances in one call by separating coordinates in the parameter with " | "

Comment: oh thanks will look at it...can you throw the link ?

Comment: @anishparajuli Google Distance Matrix API Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

Comment: Keep in mind the maximum URL length when sending multiple requests at once. I doubt that 170 locations can be done with one request.

Comment: @Darko Well actually it can't because the URL length is more than 2000 with 170 locations, but I wrote some specific code so that it makes a request when a total length of 1800 is exceeded, so i got multiple requests and result but parsed them into one result afterwards

Answer (score 3):

Apple's geocoding object is not intended for bulk-geocoding. See the `CLGeocoder` Class Reference in Xcode for more information. A brief excerpt:

> Applications should be conscious of how they use geocoding. Geocoding
>   requests are rate-limited for each app, so making **too many requests
>   in a short period of time may cause some of the requests to fail**.
>   (When the maximum rate is exceeded, the geocoder returns an error
>   object with the value kCLErrorNetwork to the associated completion
>   handler.) Here are some rules of thumb for using this class
>   effectively:
>
> Send at most one geocoding request for any one user action.
>
> If the user performs multiple actions that involve geocoding the same
>   location, reuse the results from the initial geocoding request instead
>   of starting individual requests for each action.
>
> When you want to update the user’s current location automatically
>   (such as when the user is moving), issue new geocoding requests only
>   when the user has moved a significant distance and after a reasonable
>   amount of time has passed. For example, in a typical situation, **you
>   should not send more than one geocoding request per minute**.

(Emphasis added by me.)

The summary is that you can't do what you are trying to do with Apple's `CLGeocoder` class.

You are only supposed to submit a single geocoding request for a user action, and then typically no more than one geocoding request per minute.

You'll need to license a third party geocoding service (and probably pay for it) in order to do bulk geocoding or reverse-geocoding.

Comment: Thanks, due to your response I used other keywords to search on my problem and found this question which mentions some API's for reverse-geocoding 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513134/how-to-reverse-geocode-without-google