# Geolocation script not returning value

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am trying to use Javascript for finding user location but it is not giving me any value, my code is below

```
<script>
                        window.onload = function() {
                          var startPos;
                          var geoSuccess = function(position) {
                            startPos = position;
                            document.getElementById('startLat').innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
                            document.getElementById('startLon').innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;
                          };
                          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess);
                        };
                    </script>
                    <?php echo "<script> getCurrentPosition('startLat') </script>"; ?>
```

Comment: what is `<script> getCurrentPosition('startLat') </script>`

Comment: Did it ask for grant of permission?

Comment: Bravo please give me the right way of getting the latitude and longitude from the function using php.

Comment: Wkoppel It did ask before I copy it from Google

Answer (score 2):

The [HTML5 Geolocation](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) API allows you to get a user's Latitude/Longitude with some JavaScript (if the browser is compatible, and if the user allows access to his/her location).

You can then reverse-geocode the location to get an address, there are several [free reverse-geocoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513134/how-to-reverse-geocode-without-google) services other than Google's API.

you can also check out this link [How to get geographical location of an IP address in PHP](http://burnignorance.com/php-programming-tips/how-to-get-geographical-location-of-an-ip-address-in-php/) for more understanding

Example:

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, How to execute it using php?

Comment: i attach one article link you can check that this may be help you .

Answer (score 1):

If you have elements with id's "startLat" and "startLon" in your HTML, it'll work

Just add in HTML:

```
<p id="startLat"></p>
<p id="startLon"></p>
```

You can delete this line, actually:

```
<?php echo "<script> getCurrentPosition('startLat') </script>"; ?>
```

Comment: I want to use the latitude and longitude in php

Answer (score 0):

To use Latitude/Longitude in your PHP you can send [the values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53170391/10611836) via JS

In HTML

```
<script>
    function sendData(value) {
       var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
       request.open('post', 'DESTINATION.PHP', true);
       request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
       request.send('data=' + value);
    }
</script>
```

Or as a hidden form input
 and access in PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
   $data = $_POST['data'];
   // Do stuff...
}
```

Comment: I think Op wants a solution in Javascript.

Comment: In [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53170518/10611836) he want to use the latitude and longitude in php. Thought it helps him